# Using Numpy to create Yahoo finance price table

Tags: python, url, numpy

Without using matplotlib finance module. I like to get the url data into a numpy array. 
where I can to column heading to do math. Like:

```
prices = r.adj_close
```

From: 
http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/finance_work2.html

except I dont want to use the:

```
fh = finance.fetch_historical_yahoo(ticker, startdate, enddate)
# a numpy record array with fields: date, open, high, low, close, volume, adj_close)

r = mlab.csv2rec(fh); fh.close()
r.sort()
```

Using manually create the url:

```
        url = http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?a=2&c=2011&b=30&e=7&d=7&g=d&f=2011&s=msft&ignore=.csv

        f = urllib.urlopen(url)
        fr = f.read()



        hdata = np.asarray(fr, dtype='object')
        prices = hdata.adj_close
        print prices
```

Comment: read the question. I like to get the url data into a numpy array.

Comment: What doesn't work about the code you have now? What's the error message? And, if it's a question, _phrase it as a question_. There are no questions in your post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use numpy.loadtxt() to load csv:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
import urllib
url = "http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?a=2&c=2011&b=30&e=7&d=7&g=d&f=2011&s=msft&ignore=.csv"
f = urllib.urlopen(url)
title = f.readline().strip().split(",")
data = np.loadtxt(f, dtype=np.float, delimiter=",", converters={0: pl.datestr2num}))
```

the first column is date, so use pylab.datestr2num to convert it to number.

Comment: "pylab.datestr2num to convert it to number"? is there any way to keep as date. Im not familar with why you changed it. I need date as date. also, How would I do prices = data.adj_close?

Comment: literals prob, I get it.  Maybe use date as object.

Comment: prices = data[:,6] or prices = data[:, title.index("Adj Close")]

Comment: Because calculate with number is easier than date, and you can use pl.num2date() to convert number back to date object when you want to output.

Comment: Trying to use the above to insert np array into Mysql. does not work. when a use list (f) it work but when I try into in Mysql with array it has a problem...What transform do I need to do to insert into database.

Comment: use data.tolist() to convert ndarray to list, and then insert list in to db.

Comment: Tried data.tolist() didnt work, compared the data before and after with print data, data.tolist(), print data. The output was the same. The row elements need to parsed to insert into db

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to load `pylab` for time string conversion, you can use the `mktime` function as a lambda:

```
import numpy as np
import urllib
import time 
url = "http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?a=2&c=2011&b=30&e=7&d=7&g=d&f=2011&s=msft&ignore=.csv" 
f = urllib.urlopen(url) 
title = f.readline().strip().split(",") 
data = np.loadtxt(f, dtype={'names': ('dtime', 'open', 'high','low','close','volume','aclose'),
                            'formats': ('u4', 'f8', 'f8','f8','f8','u4','f8')}, 
                     delimiter=",", 
                     converters={0: lambda y:int(time.mktime(time.strptime(y,'%Y-%m-%d')))})
```

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to use `S10` to tell numpy that the first entity is a string with length 10. This way, you don't need to use lambda.

```
data = np.loadtxt(f, dtype={'names': ('dtime', 'open', 'high','low','close','volume','aclose'), 'formats': ('S10', '<f8', '<f8','<f8','<f8','i','<f8')}, 
                             delimiter="," )

i=integer, <f8 =0.256, f8=0.25600001298, S10="MM-DD-YYYY"
```

For more info on f, f8, u4, S, u8 etc, visit this [link](http://helpful.knobs-dials.com/index.php/Python_usage_notes_-_Numpy,_scipy).